# C# Excel Interop count visible rows

Tags: c#, excel, interop

How can I get the total number of visible rows?

I tried the following:
1)

```
Excel.Range range;
range = ws.UsedRange;

int rCnt = 0;
rCnt = range.Rows.Count;
```

`rCnt = 1` after execution

2)

```
var countRows = ws.Rows.Count;
```

`countRows = 1048576` after execution

Both `rCnt` and `countRows` sould return `31` -> total number of rows that are visible

Comment: define visible - to excel, all rows are visible unless you specifically hid them, or do you mean "on screen"?

Comment: When I open an Excel Workbook there are only 31 rows visible on screen

Comment: Ok so its not the number of visible cells but the ones on screen - excel is telling you how many are visible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [VisibleRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.window.visiblerange.aspx)

> Returns a Range object that represents the range of cells that are
>   visible in the window or pane. If a column or row is partially
>   visible, it's included in the range.

For example, having defined

```
var xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
if (xlApp == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("EXCEL could not be started. Check that your office installation and project references are correct.");
    return;
}
xlApp.Visible = true;

var wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
var ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];
```

then you can do

```
var test = xlApp.ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Rows.Count;
```

Comment: Can you also please tell me how I should define the `xlApp`?

Comment: Updated as per your request

Comment: I'm getting `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on `var test` ... this happens because I'm trying to get the total rows after pressing a button outside the ThisAddIn class?

Comment: Doesn't this exclude rows that are Visible but are not currently shown on the screen (like ones further down the worksheet, out of view of the window)?